# Towers of Hanoi with Stacks Java

Tags: java, stack, towers-of-hanoi

I am working on a Towers of Hanoi problem in Java.  I chose to use Stacks as the pegs and have everything working except for the move method.  I have the specification and a JUnit test class and am currently passing 6 of the 7 tests but am failing on the move test.  The specs are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Here is my `Towers` class:

```
package edu.metrostate.ics240.p2.towers;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Towers {
    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 64;
    private static final int MIN_PEG = 1;
    private static final int MAX_PEG = 3;
    private static Stack<Integer>[] tower = new Stack[4];
    private int numOfRings;

public Towers(int n) {
    if (n < 1 || n > MAX_SIZE) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Number of rings (%s) cannot be less than 1 or exceed 64 ", n));
    numOfRings = n;
    tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfRings; i++)
        tower[1].push(i);
}
public Towers() {
    numOfRings = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfRings; i++)
        tower[1].push(i);
}

private static void pegCheck(int pegNumber){
    if (pegNumber < MIN_PEG || pegNumber > MAX_PEG) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Peg number (%s) cannot be less than 1 or exceed 3 ", pegNumber));
}
public int getRingCount(int pegNumber) {
    pegCheck(pegNumber);

    switch (pegNumber) {
    case 1:
        if (tower[1].isEmpty()) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return tower[1].size();
    case 2:
        if (tower[2].isEmpty()) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return tower[2].size();
    case 3:
        if (tower[3].isEmpty()) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return tower[3].size();
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
public int getTopDiameter(int pegNumber) {
    pegCheck(pegNumber);

    switch (pegNumber) {
    case 1:
        if(getRingCount(1) > 0){
            return tower[1].get(tower[1].peek() - tower[1].size());
        }else
            return 0;
    case 2:
        if(getRingCount(2) > 0){
            return tower[2].get(tower[2].peek() - tower[2].size());
        }else
            return 0;
    case 3:
        if(getRingCount(3) > 0){
            return tower[3].get(tower[3].peek() - tower[3].size());
        }else
            return 0;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
public boolean move(int startPeg, int endPeg) {
    pegCheck(startPeg);
    pegCheck(endPeg);
    Stack<Integer> startTower = tower[startPeg];
    Stack<Integer> endTower = tower[endPeg];


    if (getRingCount(startPeg) > 0 && endPeg != startPeg && getRingCount(endPeg) > 0 && getTopDiameter(startPeg) < getTopDiameter(endPeg)) {
        int topRing = startTower.pop();
        endTower.push(topRing);
        return true;
    }else
        return false;
}
}
```

and finally the JUnit test(s):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import edu.metrostate.ics240.p2.towers.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class TowersTest {
    private static final int MAX_NUM_RINGS = 64;
    private static final long SEED = 20170604001L;
    private static final Random RAND = new Random(SEED);

@Test
public void testDefaultConstruction() {
    Towers t = new Towers();
    assertEquals(5, t.getRingCount(1));
    assertEquals(0, t.getRingCount(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getRingCount(3));

    assertEquals(1, t.getTopDiameter(1));
    assertEquals(0, t.getTopDiameter(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getTopDiameter(3));
}

@Test
public void testConstruction() {
    int numRings = RAND.nextInt(MAX_NUM_RINGS);
    Towers t = new Towers(numRings);
    assertEquals(numRings, t.getRingCount(1));
    assertEquals(0, t.getRingCount(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getRingCount(3));

    assertEquals(1, t.getTopDiameter(1));
    assertEquals(0, t.getTopDiameter(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getTopDiameter(3));
}

@Test
public void testMove() {
    int numRings = RAND.nextInt(64);

    Towers t = new Towers(numRings);

    assertTrue(t.move(1, 2));
    assertEquals(numRings - 1, t.getRingCount(1));
    assertEquals(1, t.getRingCount(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getRingCount(3));

    assertEquals(2, t.getTopDiameter(1));
    assertEquals(1, t.getTopDiameter(2));
    assertEquals(0, t.getTopDiameter(3));

    assertTrue(t.move(1, 3));
    assertEquals(numRings - 2, t.getRingCount(1));
    assertEquals(1, t.getRingCount(2));
    assertEquals(1, t.getRingCount(3));

    assertEquals(3, t.getTopDiameter(1));
    assertEquals(1, t.getTopDiameter(2));
    assertEquals(2, t.getTopDiameter(3));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidConstructor(){
    Towers t = null;
    try {
        t = new Towers(0); // illegal value
        fail("Expected exception");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }

    try {
        t = new Towers(MAX_NUM_RINGS + 1); // illegal value
        fail("Expected exception");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }
}
@Test
public void testPreconditionGetRingCount() {
    Towers t = new Towers();
    try {
        t.getRingCount(0);
        fail("Exception expected");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }
    try {
        t.getRingCount(4);
        fail("Exception expected");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }
}

@Test
public void testPreconditionTopRing() {
    Towers t = new Towers();
    try {
        t.getTopDiameter(0);
        fail("Exception expected");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }
    try {
        t.getTopDiameter(4);
        fail("Exception expected");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // expected
    }
}

@Test
public void testIllegalMoves(){
    Towers t = new Towers();

    t.move(1, 2);
    t.move(1, 3);

    assertFalse(t.move(1, 1)); // can't move to itself
    assertFalse(t.move(1, 2)); // moving larger ring to smaller
    assertFalse(t.move(1, 3)); // moving larger ring to smaller
    assertFalse(t.move(3, 2));
}
}
```

I think I know where my issue lies.  The precondition of `getTopDiameter()` returns the top ring size if `getRingCount(pegNum) > 0` but returns 0 if the stack is empty or there are no rings on the peg.  Since `tower[1]` is the only peg that gets initialized with rings and the other two do not, `getTopDiameter()` returns 0 since there are no rings currently on `tower[2]` and `tower[3]`.  In the `move()` method one of the preconditions requires that `getTopdiameter(startPeg)` be less than `getTopDiamater(endPeg)` but if the `endPeg` was initialized with 0 rings and is therefore empty, `getTopDiamater(endPeg)` returns 0 which is obviously not less than 1 in this case.  I just cannot figure this bit out.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

*UPDATE*
revised code that is passing all test cases:

```
package edu.metrostate.ics240.p2.towers;

import java.util.Stack;

public class Towers {
    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 64;
    private static final int MIN_PEG = 1;
    private static final int MAX_PEG = 3;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Stack<Integer>[] tower = new Stack[4];
    private int numOfRings;

public Towers(int n) {
    if (n < 1 || n > MAX_SIZE)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Number of rings (%s) cannot be less than 1 or exceed 64 ", n));
    numOfRings = n;
    tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int i = numOfRings; i >= 1; i--)
        tower[1].push(i);
}

public Towers() {
    numOfRings = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    tower[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
    tower[3] = new Stack<Integer>();
    for (int i = numOfRings; i >= 1; i--)
        tower[1].push(i);
}

private static void pegCheck(int pegNumber) {
    if (pegNumber < MIN_PEG || pegNumber > MAX_PEG)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Peg number (%s) cannot be less than 1 or exceed 3 ", pegNumber));
}

public int getRingCount(int pegNumber) {
    pegCheck(pegNumber);
    if (tower[pegNumber].isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else
        return tower[pegNumber].size();
}

public int getTopDiameter(int pegNumber) {
    pegCheck(pegNumber);
    if (getRingCount(pegNumber) > 0) {
        return tower[pegNumber].get(tower[pegNumber].size() - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}

public boolean move(int startPeg, int endPeg) {
    pegCheck(startPeg);
    pegCheck(endPeg);

    if (endPeg != startPeg) {
        if (getRingCount(startPeg) > 0) {
            if (getRingCount(endPeg) == 0 || getTopDiameter(startPeg) < getTopDiameter(endPeg)) {
                int topRing = tower[startPeg].pop();
                tower[endPeg].push(topRing);
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> In the move() method one of the preconditions requires that getTopdiameter(startPeg) be less than getTopDiamater(endPeg) but if the endPeg was initialized with 0 rings and is therefore empty, getTopDiamater(endPeg) returns 0 which is obviously not less than 1 in this case

But if you read the preconditions in the image you provide - it is stating that `getTopdiameter(startPeg)` be less than `getTopDiamater(endPeg)` **if `endPeg` has at least one ring** so to write this as conditions you need

```
getRingCount(endPeg) > 0 && getTopdiameter(startPeg) < getTopDiamater(endPeg))
```

**-- Edit --**

You need to separate the conditions into different if statements (or have and or condition also) to handle the case when the towers have no pegs - currently with your conditions as is, it fails on the first move as the condition `getRingCount(endPeg) > 0` will be false. If `getRingCount == 0` then you can just do the move without needing to check if the diameters are compatible. For readability I would suggest you separate your conditions out initially - you can always combine them as required later - something like this pseudo code

```
if not same peg
   if start peg has rings
      if end peg is empty or (end peg has rings and diameters are compatible) 
          do move and return true             
 return false
```

Comment: This is the condition I used in `move()`:                                                               `if (getRingCount(startPeg) > 0 && endPeg != startPeg && getRingCount(endPeg) > 0 && getTopDiameter(startPeg) < getTopDiameter(endPeg))`

Comment: Arr yes, I see that now sorry, it got lost in the single line of all your conditions and the way you described it sound like it was missing.

Comment: Yeah I apologize I am still a student.  Still learning all the tricks of the trade.

Comment: No problem, I see what the problem is now and I've written some pseudo code. See my edit above.

Comment: I appreciate it, I will give it a look and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I was able to pass all the tests by adjusting a few things and utilizing your pseudo code.  Thanks again.  I have added the revised code to the op.

Comment: Well done. Another thing for you to consider might be to look at your switches: Each case is executing the same code just with hard coded int values - which is the same value that you passed in. Imagine updating this  if you could have 10 pegs!

Comment: Yeah I was thinking those switches were ugly.  I am allowed to add methods and classes or basically anything I want to the project, what would you suggest?

Comment: in those cases you can just remove the switch altogether. You have the value passed into the method as `pegNumber` so instead of accessing the array index with `1` for example, just use `pegNumber`

Comment: Awesome that cleaned up the code quite nicely!  Seriously, thank you for all of your help on this.  I re-updated the code above to reflect the changes.